# Ways to Generate SDK in many languages from common DSL?

Tags: sdk

We have a RESTful API and are writing SDKs in Javascript, Ruby, and PHP.  Instead of maintaining all of these different code bases, does anyone have thoughts on a tool where we could write it in one common DSL and have it interpretted into as many (programming) languages as we want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tool that accomplishes that:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen

Note that this shouldn't be seen as a panacea, more like 'get it started'.

Comment: Nice, also AWS created this service:   https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-api-gateway-build-and-run-scalable-application-backends/

We also support an API-first development model so that definitions can be created while the implementation is still underway. Once the APIs have been defined, the API Gateway can create JavaScript, iOS, and Android SDKs with a couple of clicks (we’ll add even more languages in the future).

Comment: For swagger-codegen, you may want to check out the `develop_2.0` branch, which contains the latest bug fixes and enhancements.